# Inline (Single File) vs. CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET if the code and the asp.net markup is in one ascx file for example for a user control,would it perform poorly compared to a User control with Code Behind using a cs file and a designer.cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the initial compilation time; when your app first starts up.

With a code-behind file you can pre-compile things and deliver a dll to the server that's ready to go.  With inline code, the framework *will* have to compile your code into an assembly when the app starts.  But after this point compiled code is compiled code, and it just doesn't matter.

Comment: But it does not take *that* long. And, as a benefit, you get the ability to update page code without calling `iisreset`, which would take hours to complete.

Answer (score 2):

for performance it will not make any difference, although for maintainability reasons, you should keep your code behind separated from your markup.

Comment: I am trying to develop some usercontrols which I want to deploy dynamically using file upload to the website and found that the code behind ones were not getting loaded and the ones with the inline code worked fine and thus wanted to know performace implications if any

Answer (score 2):

An interesting fact - Microsoft [sometimes suggests](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247) you create a code-behind assemblies for your ASP.net pages for maintainability and presentation/business logics separation.

However, when you take a look at how SharePoint is built, its pages (for instance, `/_layouts/workflow.aspx`) are full of inline code.
They actually do reveal that the speed of inline code is [the same as code-behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx):

> Another myth is that codebehind is
>   faster than inline, which is
>   absolutely false. It doesn't matter
>   where your code for your ASP.NET
>   application lives, whether in a
>   codebehind file or inline with the
>   ASP.NET page.

This makes me think that performance and maintainability is not always the main reason why you choose inline code over code-behind.

Comment: Sharepoint is done that way because they *have* to do it that way.  Otherwise you'd have to deploy assemblies, iisreset, all that junk, every time you wanted to update a page.  The "myth" that you describe covers run-time performance.  The first time you hit the page there will still be a minor delay while the inline code is compiled, but from then on it behaves just like precompiled code.